# Making good a newly chased backbox

Tags: electrical

This is my first attempt at chasing out a backbox for a socket / switch.

[image: messy backbox chasing]

Unfortunately, it looks a bit rubbish. Unfortunately the switch is the same size as the back box. If it'd been slightly bigger then it would have sat proud of the wall and hidden the imperfections, and would have sat level.

As it is, it's slightly proud and even though I think I did an ok job cutting a tidy hole you can see it really badly.

What's the best way to fix this?

I guess I can use some plastic shims behind to level.

What about the edges? Do I just plaster around the box, or is that bad practice?

Are all back boxes exact same size as the faceplates? Are trims available to hide the hole?

Please disregard the cable below. That's probably going to go into some trunking.

Many thanks,
Dave

Comment: Faceplates for most electrical boxes for switches/outlets/light are usually bigger than the hole.  For what you have can use drywall mud or paintable caulking to fill the opening.  Maybe use painters tape on the box first to prevent binding when removing the box in the future.

Comment: @crisp659 look please this is not a North American install. for a while I have been thinking are you a bot always comments, many times way off. Even worse than the internet only electricians that get so wordy and well maybe some of those are bots also ,,, just look usually the last to answer and unless the same as another question ,,, well just my option

Comment: @EdBeal  Not a bot, so if I do make a mistake, please let me know so I can learn.  Sometimes I don't believe I have all the information so prefer making a comment to maybe help, instead of an answer that is wrong.

Comment: @EdBeal Can you explain what is wrong with crip659's comment? It seems reasonably helpful and I don't see anything that is specific to one locale.

Comment: @elliot Alderson the comment was about US products when this doesn't look like a listed US device that has a faceplate.

Comment: @EdBeal Are you saying that **only** US products have faceplates that are bigger than the hole? Was there something wrong with the suggestion to "use drywall mud or paintable caulking"? This seemed like a helpful and reasonable suggestion to me.

Comment: @ Elliot Anderson read my comment below the answer if it is not a listed product it would not be code compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution, but I have a 3D printer so I fixed up the alignment with some caulk behind the box, and a shim around the socket:

[image: Fused switch in backbox with shim]

I may or may not remove the shim and try and plaster and paint around it - once I've finished the rest of the job.

Comment: Nice! Looks a lot like the typical US-style cover plate. Most (not all) US stuff is one of a few standard styles with single, double, triple and sometimes larger cover plates available. The great thing I discovered is larger single plates - perfect for covering up problems like this. But the UK/Europe stuff is entirely different.

Comment: With the exception of the cordage coming out a hole in the wall the solution looks much better.

Comment: I’ll get rid of that shortly :)